# Using python's wx.grid, how can you merge columns?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Here is the table I have created so far.

[image]

Here is what I would like it to look like, with the columns merged.

[image]

I would like to merge the columns Yesterday and Today across three columns each. So Yesterday would be above Equity, Volatility, and Cash. Then likewise for Today. I have found one function called `wx.grid.SetColSize(self, int col, int width)`, but it didn't have any effect. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my code as well.

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Strategies' Allocations")
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        button_refresh = wx.Button(self.panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label='Refresh')
        button_refresh.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.refresh)

        self.myGrid1 = gridlib.Grid(self.panel)
        self.myGrid1.CreateGrid(2, 6)

        self.myGrid1.SetRowLabelSize(60)
        self.myGrid1.SetRowLabelValue(0, "")
        self.myGrid1.SetRowLabelValue(1, "ABRVXX")

        for i in range(6):
            self.myGrid1.SetColSize(i, 60)

        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelValue(0, "")
        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelValue(1, "Yesterday")
        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelValue(2, "")
        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelValue(3, "")
        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelValue(4, "Today")
        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelValue(5, "")

        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(0, 0, "Equity")
        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(0, 1, "Volatility")
        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(0, 2, "Cash")
        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(0, 3, "Equity")
        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(0, 4, "Volatility")
        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(0, 5, "Cash")

        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
        self.myGrid1.SetDefaultCellAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_TOP )
        # ******************************* #

        self.myGrid2 = gridlib.Grid(self.panel)
        self.myGrid2.CreateGrid(2, 6)

        for i in range(6):
            self.myGrid2.SetColSize(i, 60)

        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelValue(0, "")
        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelValue(1, "Yesterday")
        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelValue(2, "")
        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelValue(3, "")
        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelValue(4, "Today")
        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelValue(5, "")

        self.myGrid2.SetCellValue(0, 0, "Treasury")
        self.myGrid2.SetCellValue(0, 1, "Volatility")
        self.myGrid2.SetCellValue(0, 2, "Cash")
        self.myGrid2.SetCellValue(0, 3, "Treasury")
        self.myGrid2.SetCellValue(0, 4, "Volatility")
        self.myGrid2.SetCellValue(0, 5, "Cash")

        self.myGrid2.SetRowLabelSize(60)
        self.myGrid2.SetRowLabelValue(0, "")
        self.myGrid2.SetRowLabelValue(1, "ABRXIV")

        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
        self.myGrid2.SetDefaultCellAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_TOP )
        # ****************************** #

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.myGrid1, 1, wx.TOP|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, 2)
        sizer.Add(self.myGrid2, 1, wx.TOP|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, 2)
        sizer.Add(button_refresh, 1, wx.RIGHT|wx.LEFT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, 50)

        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.panel.SetSize((500,400))
        self.SetSize((500,400))
        self.panel.Layout()

    def refresh(self, event):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: not sure what you mean. Can you give some screenshot with what you are looking for with the data in the grid?

Comment: @Igor I added a screenshot to show what I would like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and dirty way is to dump the column labels `SetColLabelSize(0)` and add the headings as cells.
Then adjust the cell spans just for those cells with `SetCellSize()`.
Below I have altered myGrid1 but not myGrid2.

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Strategies' Allocations")
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        button_refresh = wx.Button(self.panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label='Refresh')
        button_refresh.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.refresh)

        self.myGrid1 = gridlib.Grid(self.panel)
        self.myGrid1.CreateGrid(3, 6)

        self.myGrid1.SetRowLabelSize(80)
        self.myGrid1.SetRowLabelValue(0, "")
        self.myGrid1.SetRowLabelValue(1, "")
        self.myGrid1.SetRowLabelValue(2, "2")

        for i in range(6):
            self.myGrid1.SetColSize(i, 60)

#        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelValue(0, "")
#        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelValue(1, "Yesterday")
#        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelValue(2, "")
#        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelValue(3, "")
#        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelValue(4, "Today")
#        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelValue(5, "")

        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelSize(0)
        self.myGrid1.SetCellSize(0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(0, 0, "Yesterday")
        self.myGrid1.SetCellSize(0, 3, 1, 3)
        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(0, 3, "Today")

        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(1, 0, "Equity")
        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(1, 1, "Volatility")
        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(1, 2, "Cash")
        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(1, 3, "Equity")
        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(1, 4, "Volatility")
        self.myGrid1.SetCellValue(1, 5, "Cash")

        self.myGrid1.SetColLabelAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
        self.myGrid1.SetDefaultCellAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_TOP )
        # ******************************* #

        self.myGrid2 = gridlib.Grid(self.panel)
        self.myGrid2.CreateGrid(2, 6)

        for i in range(6):
            self.myGrid2.SetColSize(i, 60)

        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelValue(0, "")
        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelValue(1, "Yesterday")
        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelValue(2, "")
        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelValue(3, "")
        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelValue(4, "Today")
        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelValue(5, "")

        self.myGrid2.SetCellValue(0, 0, "Treasury")
        self.myGrid2.SetCellValue(0, 1, "Volatility")
        self.myGrid2.SetCellValue(0, 2, "Cash")
        self.myGrid2.SetCellValue(0, 3, "Treasury")
        self.myGrid2.SetCellValue(0, 4, "Volatility")
        self.myGrid2.SetCellValue(0, 5, "Cash")

        self.myGrid2.SetRowLabelSize(60)
        self.myGrid2.SetRowLabelValue(0, "")
        self.myGrid2.SetRowLabelValue(1, "2")

        self.myGrid2.SetColLabelAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
        self.myGrid2.SetDefaultCellAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_TOP )
        # ****************************** #

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.myGrid1, 1, wx.TOP|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, 2)
        sizer.Add(self.myGrid2, 1, wx.TOP|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, 2)
        sizer.Add(button_refresh, 1, wx.RIGHT|wx.LEFT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, 50)

        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.panel.SetSize((500,400))
        self.SetSize((500,400))
        self.panel.Layout()

    def refresh(self, event):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: For what I'm trying to do this gets the job done. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AlexF I have added back adjusted images, after your edit on both answers. Feel free to re-edit, if there is still a privacy issue.

Comment: this is great. Still very helpful for those who needs it, but keeps the privacy. Thanks for being accommodating.

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to be especially simple, but I think you should achieve what you want by defining a class deriving from `wxGridCellAttrProvider` and overriding its `GetColumnHeaderRenderer()` method to return a "do nothing" `wxGridColumnHeaderRenderer` for the columns you want to be merged and the standard renderer (returned by the base class `GetColumnHeaderRenderer()`) for the other ones. Then you just need to call `SetAttrProvider()` with your custom attribute provider object on your table object.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the GridLabelRenderer sample in the wxPython demo.  It is an example of drawing custom labels for grid rows and columns, based on the classes in `wx.lib.mixins.gridlabelrenderer`.  With these classes it becomes pretty easy to draw the labels however you want. You just need to override the appropriate Draw methods.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @RobinDunn here is a version (of sorts) using the `GridLabelRenderer`, which isn't as complicated as it first looks.
It does have a quirk or two however.
Notice the use of `l` and `r` to store `rect.left` and `rect.right`.
It's done this way because if you adjust `rect.left`, `right.right` adjusts as well, without you asking it to.
I assume that this is because the `rect` has a size, so if you adjust 1 element, the other compensates.
Note also, that you have to declare the blank column headers, otherwise they will revert to the standard "A,B,C,D....." sequence.

```
import wx
import wx.grid as grid
import wx.lib.mixins.gridlabelrenderer as glr
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyGrid(grid.Grid, glr.GridWithLabelRenderersMixin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        grid.Grid.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        glr.GridWithLabelRenderersMixin.__init__(self)

class TextLabelRenderer(glr.GridLabelRenderer):
    def __init__(self, text, colspan,bgcolour=None):
        self.text = text
        self.colspan = colspan
        if bgcolour is not None:
            self.bgcolour = bgcolour
        else:
            self.bgcolour = "white"

    def Draw(self, grid, dc, rect, col):
        if self.colspan == 0:
            rect.SetSize((0,0))
        if self.colspan > 1:
            add_cols = self.colspan - 1
            l = rect.left
            r = rect.right + ((rect.Size.x -1) * add_cols)
            rect.left = l
            rect.right = r
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(self.bgcolour))
        dc.SetPen(wx.TRANSPARENT_PEN)
        dc.DrawRectangleRect(rect)
        hAlign, vAlign = grid.GetColLabelAlignment()
        text = self.text
        if self.colspan != 0:
            self.DrawBorder(grid, dc, rect)
        self.DrawText(grid, dc, rect, text, hAlign, vAlign)

class TestPanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, size=(800,300))
        ROWS = 6
        COLS = 11
        g = MyGrid(self, size=(100,100))
        g.CreateGrid(ROWS, COLS)
        g.SetColLabelRenderer(0, TextLabelRenderer('Contract',1,"lightblue"))
        g.SetColLabelRenderer(1, TextLabelRenderer('Yesterday',3,"lightgreen"))
        g.SetColLabelRenderer(2, TextLabelRenderer('',0))
        g.SetColLabelRenderer(3, TextLabelRenderer('',0))
        g.SetColLabelRenderer(4, TextLabelRenderer('Today',4,"green"))
        g.SetColLabelRenderer(5, TextLabelRenderer('',0))
        g.SetColLabelRenderer(6, TextLabelRenderer('',0))
        g.SetColLabelRenderer(7, TextLabelRenderer('',0))
        g.SetColLabelRenderer(8, TextLabelRenderer('Other',1,"gold"))
       # g.SetColLabelRenderer(9, TextLabelRenderer('',0))
        g.SetRowLabelSize(0)
        g.SetCellValue(0, 1, "Equity")
        g.SetCellValue(0, 2, "Volatility")
        g.SetCellValue(0, 3, "Cash")
        g.SetCellValue(0, 4, "Equity")
        g.SetCellValue(0, 5, "Volatility")
        g.SetCellValue(0, 6, "Cash")
        g.SetCellValue(1, 0, "2")
        g.SetCellValue(1, 1, "1500")
        g.SetCellValue(1, 2, "23")
        g.SetCellValue(1, 3, "2300")
        g.SetCellValue(1, 4, "1400")
        g.SetCellValue(1, 5, "26")
        g.SetCellValue(1, 6, "2400")
        g.SetColLabelAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
        g.SetDefaultCellAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_TOP )

        g1 = MyGrid(self, size=(100,100))
        g1.CreateGrid(ROWS, COLS)
        g1.SetColLabelRenderer(0, TextLabelRenderer('Contract',1,"lightblue"))
        g1.SetColLabelRenderer(1, TextLabelRenderer('Yesterday',3,"lightgreen"))
        g1.SetColLabelRenderer(2, TextLabelRenderer('',0))
        g1.SetColLabelRenderer(3, TextLabelRenderer('',0))
        g1.SetColLabelRenderer(4, TextLabelRenderer('Today',3,"green"))
        g1.SetColLabelRenderer(5, TextLabelRenderer('',0))
        g1.SetColLabelRenderer(6, TextLabelRenderer('',0))
        g1.SetColLabelRenderer(7, TextLabelRenderer('Other',2,"gold"))
        g1.SetColLabelRenderer(8, TextLabelRenderer('',0))
        g1.SetRowLabelSize(0)
        g1.SetCellValue(0, 1, "Equity")
        g1.SetCellValue(0, 2, "Volatility")
        g1.SetCellValue(0, 3, "Cash")
        g1.SetCellValue(0, 4, "Equity")
        g1.SetCellValue(0, 5, "Volatility")
        g1.SetCellValue(0, 6, "Cash")
        g1.SetCellValue(1, 0, "2")
        g1.SetCellValue(1, 1, "500")
        g1.SetCellValue(1, 2, "23")
        g1.SetCellValue(1, 3, "12300")
        g1.SetCellValue(1, 4, "11400")
        g1.SetCellValue(1, 5, "26")
        g1.SetCellValue(1, 6, "12400")
        g1.SetColLabelAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
        g1.SetDefaultCellAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_TOP )
        self.Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.Sizer.Add(g, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.Sizer.Add(g1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.Show()
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = TestPanel()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question mentioned using wx.Grid, but for those who don't need this, [wx.GridBagSizer](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.GridBagSizer.html) can be used instead. It allows items to span multiple columns and/or rows.